# User password reset in Symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I'm implementing a user password reset in Symfony 1.4, already using SfGuard.

Desired process:

- user clicks link
- gets email with url and expiring token
- goes to url and provides token for authorization (in request or manually)
- resets password
- gets second email notification of password change

Any plugins / patterns implementing this?

Comment: I think that sfDoctrineGuardPlugin (http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin) implement exactly what you want

Answer (score 2):

You pretty much described the process. Here's a rough guide - since I don't know your ORM, I believe you use Propel, since this functionality exists in [sfDoctrineGuardPlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin).

- Add two fields to your sfGuardProfile User model: token and tokenExpiresAt
- Create an action (reset_request) that handles generation and e-mails the URL + token
- Link to this action from your login page etc.
- Create an action (reset_token) that looks up a user using UserProfilePeer based on the provided :token and expireAt > time()
- Present a form for the User for setting a new password and handle the submit + save user and login.

Have a look at how it's implemented in [sfGuardForgotPasswordActions](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/trunk/modules/sfGuardForgotPassword/lib/BasesfGuardForgotPasswordActions.class.php) for more inspiration.

Comment: Thx.  The code uses Doctrine for its ORM but it looks like we can work around that.  I did look for something like this in sfDoctrineGuardPlugin but apparently didn't look hard enough.

Comment: Maybe I'm a dummy but I've grepped the package six ways to Sunday and still don't see anything like a token authorization generation.  What am I missing?

Comment: Hmm, is this done with the keys used for "remember me" cookies?

Comment: I've updated the link to sfDoctrineGuardPlugin source. The key for the remember me cookie should not be used, no. See line 39 and 40, where they set a unique_key (token) and expires_at.